# Simple flex layout, top div is hidden by the following one when resizing screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overlap

I'm trying to build a simple flex layout with 5 elements nested within 3 containers, everything contained into a macro-container.

When I resize the window, however, the first element is hidden by the following one. Thank you for your help beforehand!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.macro-container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.subcontainer {
  height: 33.3%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.subcontainer1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.subcontainer2 {
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.subcontainer3 {
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item-text {
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 3;
}

.item-photo {
  min-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<div class="macro-container">

  <div class="subcontainer subcontainer1">

    <div class="item-text">
      <h2 class="item-text-heading">LOREM IPSUM</h2>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.
        Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="subcontainer subcontainer2">


    <div class="item-text">
      <h2 class="item-text-heading">LOREM IPSUM</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.
        Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item-photo">
      <img src="https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Common-dog-behaviors-explained.jpg?itok=FSzwbBoi" class="item-photo">
    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="subcontainer subcontainer3">


    <div class="item-photo">
      <img src="https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Common-dog-behaviors-explained.jpg?itok=FSzwbBoi" class="item-photo">
    </div>

    <div class="item-text">
      <h2 class="item-text-heading">LOREM IPSUM</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.
        Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
    </div>


  </div>



</div>


</html>
```

Comment: It's because you have a fixed height on your `.macro-container`. With `height: 100vh` the container cannot expand to accommodate longer content on smaller screens. So the content overlaps. Try `min-height: 100vh` instead. https://jsfiddle.net/eay86L10/

Comment: Nice one Michael, you beat me to it by 12 seconds :)

Comment: Hi michael thank you for your help. Even by setting the min-height to 100vh the first element is hidden behind the image when resizing the window (as you can see it in your snippet)